# How Many Tabs need Created in Multiple Document Signup

Tags: docusignapi

Document Signup has following case:

- Single Recipient
- Multiple Documents
- Each Document has 2 AnchorTabString

My query is "How many SignHere Tabs need created for CreateAndSendEnvelope request?"

I'm using following assignment for Tab Creation.

```
DocuSignAPI.Tab sTab = new DocuSignAPI.Tab();
sTab.Type = DocuSignAPI.TabTypeCode.SignHere;            
sTab.RecipientID = receipientID;
sTab.DocumentID = DocumentID;
sTab.AnchorTabItem = new DocuSignAPI.AnchorTab();
sTab.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = anchorTabString;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single tab definition is required within the **CreateAndSendEnvelope** request for each *unique* **AnchorTabString** value in the documents.  For example, if the anchor string **\s1\** exists in 6 different places throughout the Envelope documents, and the API request contains a single SignHere tab definition, where **AnchorTabString** is set to **\s1\** -- then DocuSign will place a SignHere tab in each of the 6 locations throughout the Envelope.

Comment: Kim, Thank you. I had wrong understanding before doing few tests on demo. I appreciate your clear answer.